# MLT framework and PHP

Tags: php

Does anyone used MLT (Media Loving Toolkit )Framework along with PHP. Is there a kick start material or code sample that i can refer for MLT - PHP API integration

Answer (score 2):

you can use the MLT library and my class. You can download it from this link https://github.com/1fer/mlt

### Features

- Cut and join videos
- Join videos with transitions
- 10 ready-made transitions with options
- Customizable Wipe transitions
- Add background audio
- Add watermark
- Add text overlay with options
- Add animated text
- Run rendering on background
- Get rendering progress percent

To install this melt library on server use this command:
`sudo apt install melt`

take a look at documentation how to use it, for example, to join clips use this code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$videoProcessing = new Andchir\VideoProcessing([
    'melt_path' => '/usr/bin/melt',
    'session_start' => true
]);
```

`// Join clips`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['joinClips' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Social.mp4',
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Dog.mp4',
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Swans.mp4'
    ]])
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out1.mp4');
```

`// Black color and fade transition`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        'colour:black', ['out' => 24],
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Dog.mp4'
    ]])
    ->addOption(['mix' => 25])
    ->addOption(['mixer' => 'luma'])
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        'colour:black', ['out' => 24]
    ]])
    ->addOption(['mix' => 25])
    ->addOption(['mixer' => 'luma'])
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out2.mp4');
```

`// Join clips with transition`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Swans.mp4',
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Dog.mp4'
    ]])
    ->addOption(['mix' => 25])
    ->addOption(['mixer' => 'luma'])
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out3.mp4');
```

`// Cut clips and join with transition`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Social.mp4', ['in' => 200, 'out' => 275]
    ]])
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Dog.mp4', ['in' => 50, 'out' => 125]
    ]])
    ->addReadyMadeTransition('fade', 25)
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Swans.mp4', ['in' => 50, 'out' => 125]
    ]])
    ->addReadyMadeTransition('shiftRightIn', 25, [
        'width' => 1280,
        'height' => 720
    ])
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out4.mp4');
```

`// Add background audio with delay`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Swans.mp4', ['in' => 50, 'out' => 125]
    ]])
    ->disableAudio()
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Dog.mp4', ['in' => 50, 'out' => 200]
    ]])
    ->addReadyMadeTransition('shiftLeftIn', 25)
    ->addBackgroundAudio($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Reformat.mp3', ['in' => 0, 'out' => 150, 'delay' => 50])
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out7.mp4');
```

`// Add watermark`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Swans.mp4', ['in' => 50, 'out' => 125]
    ]])
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Dog.mp4', ['in' => 50, 'out' => 200]
    ]])
    ->addWatermark($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/SampleLogo.png', false, [
        'distort' => 1
    ])
    ->addReadyMadeTransition('shiftLeftIn', 25)
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out8.mp4');
```

`// Add text overlay`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Swans.mp4', ['out' => 120]
    ]])
    ->addTextOverlay('This is my best video', true, [
        'fgcolour' => '#004fed',
        'olcolour' => '#fff200',
        'outline' => 3,
        'pad' => '50x0',
        'size' => 80,
        'weight' => 700,
        'style' => 'italic',
        'halign' => 'center',
        'valign' => 'top',
        'family' => 'Ubuntu'
    ])
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out10.mp4');
```

`// Animated text`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Swans.mp4', ['out' => 120]
    ]])
    ->addTextOverlay('This is my best video', true, [
        'pad' => '50x0',
        'size' => 80,
        'halign' => 'center',
        'valign' => 'top',
        'family' => 'Ubuntu',
        'slideFrom' => 'bottom',
        'duration' => 50,
        'inOpacity' => 0,
        'outOpacity' => 100
    ])
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out11.mp4');
```

`// Rendering`

```
$videoProcessing
    ->setProfile('hdv_720_25p')
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Swans.mp4', ['out' => 120]
    ]])
    ->disableAudio()
    ->addOption(['inputSource' => [
        $rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Dog.mp4', ['out' => 120]
    ]])
    ->addReadyMadeTransition('shiftLeftIn', 25)
    ->addBackgroundAudio($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/Reformat.mp3', ['out' => 215])
    ->setOutputVideoOptions($rootPath . '/uploads/tmp/out.mp4');
```

`// Start rendering in background`

```
$progressLogPath = $videoProcessing->render();
```

`// Rendering progress`

```
$percent = $videoProcessing->getRenderingPercent();
```

You can also make some filter effects like in Instagram and so on. Read more here:
https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/PluginsFilters/

Comment: Wow. This is awesome. How did you link PHP with native MLT code?

Comment: i just build the command and run it via shell_exec function.
You can take a look here for more details:
https://github.com/1fer/mlt/blob/master/classes/VideoProcessing.php:150

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I could find [Multimedia Conversion - Sub MLT Project](http://code.google.com/p/multimedia-conversion/) which was located on the [MLT Projects Wiki page](http://mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/Projects). Not sure if this is useful information or not, but maybe it will help you out.

Comment: Well i checked that one. It is more of a media format convertion project, which is also in primary stage. 
What MLT can do is, vieo mixing, chroma keying etc more than just convertion.